# Druid Security Group Setup in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group, druid

I have deployed druid latest(v26.0) version in a Clustered mode in 2 AWS EC2 instances ( 1 server for Master, Query & ZK, another dedicated for Data Server).
The master instance has the ports - `8081,8888,8082`, data server has the ports `8083,8091` open and in service. Both the instances are in same security group. I have an Application Load Balancer that listens to HTTPS with SSL enabled to access my druid console at https://druid.mycompany.com. The ALB has 1 target i.e the master instance with port 8888.
I have defined the below security group rule for both the master and data server.
[image]

I can access my druid console at https://druid.mycompany.com. However, I cant access the individual services. Errors as shown below :-
[image]

Is there anything I am missing in the security group rule ? Thanks!